# Multiple cameras with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, locking, camera

I'm writing a program that gets captures from two cameras at once using OpenCV (I'm not doing this for stereo vision). Using the standard OpenCV functions `cvCaptureFromCAM()` to get captures from the two identical cameras along with `cvQueryFrame()` being called twice in a while loop (once for each capture), I end up getting garbage images in both cameras as seen when I display them in a `cvNamedWindow`.

Alternatively, if I run each camera in their own POSIX thread (therefore same address space) I get a segmentation fault in the second thread, for which I can't figure out the cause.

Finally, I can run each camera in its own process (therefore separate address spaces) and everything runs fine. My suspicion is that there's some sort of lock-type resource that must be acquired before doing each frame query from a different camera. Hopefully someone has some ideas for how to **get both captures in the same process and same thread.** Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

What OS ?

It's very dependent on the cameras and their drivers - especially on windows using Directshow it can be complete chance if they will work together, if you need to start them in a certain order or in a certain way.

If you can run the cameras on their own in separate threads and have them write the images over some neutral system (named pipes, tcp socket, file in ramdisk) you might find that more reliable

Answer (score 0):

For each thread that uses the COM library, you must call `::CoInitializeEx( NULL,COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` once and uninitialize it when you finish the capture work.

To get both captures in the same process and same thread, did you allocate a copy for the buffer used by `cvQueryFrame()`? I suspect that your two captures share the same buffer from `cvQueryFrame()` and this buffer is actually maintained by OpenCV itself! So try make a copy for each capture and see if it works.

Hope it helps!